# Teenagers sleeping patterns and parents actions (force or let-go)

Tags: sleep, sleep-cycles, sleep-deprivation, psychologist-psychology, adolescents-teenagers

My daughter (15 years old) is very active and full of energy until she hits the sac. After five minutes she's out. This represents the perfect behaviour for bedtime process. But, she does this at 1:00 AM and sometimes even 2:30 AM and pretty much every night. The fact that she has school the morning after does not change that behaviour. Her overall productivity is not impaired. She can study math at 11:00 at night with very good concentration. She does not feel the fatigue.

She plays competitive Basketball, Volleyball, does ballet and pretty much every activity school offers. She's a pretty busy bee and feels great about it. In the morning, she a bit grumpy and her overall respect for her parents is declining. But I would say, this is a general pattern in teenagers.

Studies are clear, living this way for all her life will hurt her overall health.

Now what?

Should I force her to go to bed earlier? I have tried both, forcing and let-go and she won't change her strange habit. I like the let-go approach because my relationship with her is way better. If I force her to go to bed earlier, she fights back and argues...I loose every time. So the let-go choice is better but I feel very bad because she might be arming herself.

Is there any scientific studies explaining how to deal with this type of teenager? I think forcing brings so much frustrations on both parts that it may impair our overall health in the long run; even more than bad sleeping patterns.

Comment: [Looks like she'll do just fine](http://brandongaille.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Habits-of-Rich-and-Powerful1.jpg)